# PointLight position not updating with FlyControls

Tags: three.js

I have a scene where I've setup a camera to be right above the scene.

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 50, 10000);
camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.y = 0;
camera.position.z = 1000;
```

I then add FlyControls such that the camera is falling towards ground:

```
controls = new THREE.FlyControls( camera );
controls.movementSpeed = 200;
controls.autoForward = true;
```

In the scene we have a bunch of floating cubes at random positions (BoxGeometry of MeshLambertMaterial) I set the PointLight position to be the same as the camera position but in the scene it does not move with the camera.

```
pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xff0000, 2, 1000);
pointLight.position = camera.position;
scene.add(pointLight);
```

I've looked through all the other three.js demos with point lights and cannot figure out why it does not move with my camera. Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of frustration it just turns out we were using CanvasRenderer and not WebGLRenderer (facepalm).